# Как без использования OR выбрать все записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Как без использования OR выбрать все записи, где имя – «Юля», «Вася», «Толя», «Катя»?

Comment: Используйте `IN()` ... ?

Comment: с помощью `IN`, например...

Answer (score 2):

Используйте оператор IN:

```
select st.*
from someTable st
where st.Name in('Юля', 'Вася', 'Толя', 'Катя')
```